# How to systematically list products of sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

**Problem:** Suppose I have three sets $A$, $B$, and $C$.  Consider the product $\{A, A^c\} \times \{B, B^c\} \times \{C, C^c\}$.  There are eight elements in this product and I want to list them systematically like $D_1, D_2, \dots D_8$.

I understand that I can just list them in any way like
$$
D_1 = (A^c, B, C) \\
D_2 = (A, B, C^c)
$$
and so on.  But I want to list them in such a way that the index number will describe in a sense which element of the product I am talking about.

My eventual goal is to generalize from three sets to $n$ sets and list them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $n$ two element sets, use the integers from $0$ to $2^n-1$ written in binary.

So in your example, $5 = 101_2$ would represent $A, B^c, C$.

Comment: For $n$ two-element sets we would need an index set of size $2^n$.  So should the index set be the integers from $0$ to $2^n - 1$ instead?

Comment: $D_1$ would then be based on the binary representation of $1$ which is $1$ or equivalently $001$, so that $D_1$ is $(A^c, B^c, C)$?

Comment: @UngarLinski Yes to both questions. I fixed the typo.